# Labelling coloured region in ggplot map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am having a small challenge with labelling my ggplot map.

Here is how I plot my map in ggplot, which works well:

```
library(ggmap)
library(scales)

Kenya1_df<- as.data.frame(Kenya1_df)

theme_opts<-list(theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                       panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                       panel.background = element_blank(),
                       plot.background = element_blank(),
                       axis.line = element_blank(),
                       axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                       axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                       axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                       axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                       axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                       plot.title = element_blank()))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = Kenya1_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill =
                                       count), color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)+
  scale_fill_distiller(name="Count", palette = "Reds", breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 5))+
  #geom_text(aes(label =Kenya1_df$NAME_1, x = Kenya1_df$long, y = Kenya1_df$lat))+
  labs(title="Nice Map")
```

The output I get is good
[image]

Now here is where my problem starts, the moment I add labels using `geom_text(aes(label =Kenya1_df$NAME_1, x = Kenya1_df$long, y = Kenya1_df$lat))` , I get a very messy map.

Here is how code looks:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = Kenya1_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill =
                                       count), color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)+
  scale_fill_distiller(name="Count", palette = "Reds", breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 5))+
  geom_text(aes(label =Kenya1_df$NAME_1, x = Kenya1_df$long, y = Kenya1_df$lat))+
  labs(title="Nice Map")
```

I get this messy map

[image]

Now , in the dataset, I have a column called **count** which determines which regions should be coloured. I notice that within this dataset, there is regions with NA in the **count** dataframe and so I am assuming during labelling, all this regions are being labelled.

Here is snippet of the data
[image]

Let me provide this link to help you download the country data. Here is the link to download map data [map data](https://nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm) and this article will help in downloading [article](https://rpubs.com/spoonerf/countrymapggplot2). So with that downloaded, we assume only 5 counties have data to plot or colour

My question, is, how can I label and focus only on row values with numbers in the **count** column or if there is any other smart way of labelling without messing visibility of the map output. Note that not all regions have data, I want to focus on only those with data but still have a complete map.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but try `unique`:  `geom_text(aes(label =unique(Kenya1_df$NAME_1), x = Kenya1_df$long, y = Kenya1_df$lat))+`

Comment: @TarJae , Clever guess but I get this error ```Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (312417): label```

Comment: I am sure we have to tweak the data in your case, but I can't reproduce your example. Break it down to 10 Name_1 create a reproducible example with the long lat data.

Comment: @Tarjae Are you able to walk me through what I need to do, I  am trying to get a reproducible data but it will be challenging. I have over 300k rows and one region alone is covering close to 10k rows

Comment: Where do you get the data for lat and long for Kenya. I guess you download somehwere? Just provide the link.

Comment: @TarJae Here is the link https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm and this article will help in downloading  https://rpubs.com/spoonerf/countrymapggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are plotting a name on every vertex of every polygon in your image. You need to plot a single name at the centroid of each region. I find it's easier to work with `sf` objects if you want to do this, but it's straightforward to convert your data frame to one:

```r
library(ggplot2)

Kenya1_df<- sf::st_as_sf(Kenya1_df)

ggplot(Kenya1_df) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = count)) +
  geom_sf_label(data = sf::st_centroid(subset(Kenya1_df, !is.na(count))), 
               aes(label = NAME_1)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(name = "Count", palette = "Reds", 
                       breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 5))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

Obviously we don't have your count data, so here's how I recreated something similar to yours:

```r
Kenya1_df <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "KE", level = 1)

Kenya1_df$count <- NA

regions <- c("Kajiado", "Kitui", "Tana River", "Garissa", "Wajir", "Mandera",
             "Homa Bay", "Meru", "Murang'a", "Nyeri", "Kiambu", "Nairobi", 
             "Machakos", "Nakuru", "Elgeyo-Marakwet")

values <- c(150, 150, 1000, 1900, 500, 150, 150, 
            150, 150, 150, 500, 750, 500, 150, 150)

Kenya1_df$count[match(regions, Kenya1_df$NAME_1)] <- values
```

Comment: Looks like a clever solution. A quick one, why am I getting this error when converting my data to sf ```Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : 
  no simple features geometry column present```

Comment: @LivingstoneM you need to convert to sf before converting your SpatialPolygons data frame to a "normal" data frame. i.e., get your map data, perform your left join (or however you are matching counts to regions), but _don't_ use `as.data.frame` begore converting to sf

Answer (score 2):

Without your data, it is a little difficult to get it right. You may want to experiment something like this:

First, generate a smaller data frame for `geom_text()` only.

```
new_df<- Kenya1_df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(NAME_1) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(long=mean(long),
                   lat = mean(lat)
                   )
  
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = Kenya1_df, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill =
                                       count), color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1)+
  scale_fill_distiller(name="Count", palette = "Reds", breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 5))+
  geom_text(data=new_df, aes(label = NAME_1, x = long, y = lat))+
    labs(title="Nice Map")
```

[image]

Comment: How about I provide this link to help you download the country data. Here is the link  to download map data https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm and this article will help in downloading  https://rpubs.com/spoonerf/countrymapggplot2. So with that downloaded, we assume only 5 counties have data to plot or colour

Comment: I get this error after running this  ```Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): label```

Comment: I have revised my answer with the data may be different from yours.